# Assigning `nil` value to a generically typed variable in Swift

Tags: swift

I think `var value: T = nil` is causing error below because XCode can't convert `nil` value to the generic type T.

```
class Node<T> {
    var value: T = nil
    var next: Node

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
        self.next = Node()
    }

    init() {
        self.next = Node()
    }
}
```

The error message reads

> Could not find an overload for '_coversion' that accepts the supplied
>   arguments

Is there a way to assign `nil` value to a variable in Swift?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to declare the variable as optional:

```
var value: T? = nil
```

Unfortunately this currently seems to trigger an unimplemented compiler feature:

```
error: unimplemented IR generation feature non-fixed class layout
```

You can work around it by declaring T with a type constraint of NSObject:

```
class Node<T:NSObject> {
    var value: T? = nil
    var next: Node

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
        self.next = Node()
    }

    init() {
        self.next = Node()
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, ANOTHER limitation?

Comment: In the playground, this does not generate an error. Perhaps it's updated: var value: T? = nil

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
var value: T? = nil
```

The question mark makes the variable an optional, meaning that it can either have a value or be nil.